# Ternary operator is not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

If the state is empty, I need to show `"N/A"`, otherwise I need to parseFloat a data which I have in my state, but for now my ternary operator is not working => if the list is empty, nothing is displaying at all (instead of `"N/A"`).

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const url =
        "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5";
      try {
        const result = await axios(proxyurl + url, {
          headers: {
            Origin: "https://api.privatbank.ua/",
          },
        });
        const data = result.data.filter((item) => item.ccy !== "BTC");
        setRateList(data);
      } catch {
        console.log("Can’t access " + url + " response. Blocked by browser?");
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);




  <div className={css["currency__rate_content"]}>
    {rateList.map((item) => (
      <ul className={css["currency__rate_content_list"]} key={item.ccy}>
        <li className={css["currency__rate_content_list_item"]}>
          {item.ccy === "RUR" ? "RUB" : item.ccy}
        </li>
        <li className={css["currency__rate_content_list_item"]}>
          {rateList.length ? parseFloat(item.buy).toFixed(2) : "N/A"}
        </li>
        <li className={css["currency__rate_content_list_item"]}>
          {rateList.length ? parseFloat(item.sale).toFixed(2) : "N/A"}
        </li>
      </ul>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: If `rateList` is empty then there are no `item` iterations to map. The turnaries will not even be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

If you show an example of your state I may be able to provide a better answer but have you tried this?

```
{rateList === '' ? 'N/A' : parseFloat(item.buy).toFixed(2)}
```